# Warning message for VB.NET questions being answered with C# solution

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, questions, answers, warning

I suggest SO to show warning messages for VB.NET questions being answered with C# solution or vice versa.

Comment: **WARNING: THIS ANSWER MAY NOT HURT YOUR BRAIN. IN CASE OF EMERGENCY, [CLICK HERE](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Visual_Basic_Triple_Play.aspx)**

Comment: @Dee Jay: I've tried to help you out with your questions by removing the extraneous "PS VB Only" text, but you insist on that remaining. Your questions are appropriately tagged VB.Net. If people give you C# answers downvote them and leave a comment.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Downvoting them would be the wrong course of action. C# and VB.NET questions are rarely specific to the language itself. Any competent .NET developer should be able to read and write code in either language, and if they can't, they can use an online conversion tool. They're *extremely* accurate, a testament to how similar the source code is for both languages. Unless it's a syntactical question about VB.NET (in which case, it would *not* have a .NET or WinForms or whatever tag), you should not downvote working answers in C#.

Comment: @Cody: I agree with you 100% (but shouldn't that also mean the C# guy attempts a VB.Net solution?). This particular user makes a habit of adding bold/italic annoying text that only a VB solution will be considered. Rather than downvoting answers he feels are unhelpful he mars the questions with extraneous text (and visits meta).

Comment: @sixlettervariables: In short you don't respect VB.NET developer.

Comment: @Shog9: There is no rule to force you to post anything. Need to fulfill posting quota?

Comment: @Dee Jay: Humour is acceptable here on the Meta site. Rudeness is not. You don't get rep from comments, anyway. Not a big deal.

Comment: Also see: [Automatic translation of code examples between VB.Net and C#](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16384/automatic-translation-of-code-examples-between-vb-net-and-c)

Comment: @Cody Gray: Discrimination against VB.NET developer is a form of humour or rudeness? Be yourself. Don't afraid of those people with Little diamond ♦ or 6-figure reputations.

Comment: @Dee Jay: Shog is not discriminating against you. I'm a VB.NET developer (among other things, but it's definitely my favorite language), and I don't think that comment is offensive. Bringing your sense of humour is important on Meta. I'm not afraid of anyone; I've sassed and contradicted plenty of moderators and high-rep users when there was a reason to do so (or it was funny). Please don't make assumptions about my self-confidence. I've got plenty of it to go around.

Comment: @Gens: I don't follow? I give [VB.Net answers to VB.Net questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228665/constructor-chaining-and-null-reference-tests/6228778#6228778), C# answers to C# questions. I make it a habit of removing extraneous text from a question (like "PS VB Only") if the tags are sufficient to convey that information. Where have I disrespected VB.Net developers?

Comment: @dee: discrimination? I am, among other things, a VB dev - you *gotta* be able to laugh at yourself in this line of work.

Comment: For those who don't agree with the FR (I don't), just downvote it, please stop trying to close a legitimate feature request.

Answer (score 27):

I believe the community is well enough capable of policing this kind of issue on its own.

Since we're in the land of .NET, many times a C# answer will in fact be sufficient to get the VB asker past a particular problem. And the C# answerer is already often enough saying "sorry, this is C# code, I'm not entirely sure of the VB syntax" or some other such disclaimer.

Expanding outwards to cover the non-.NET universe, if the answer is indeed in the wrong language *and* it does not assist in answering the question, that's where we have downvotes. But if the answer helps move the needle, then the language itself is not a problem. It could even be pseudocode, for all we care.

Comment: VB basically is pseudocode.  Note, I am a VB.Net developer.

Comment: I always feel bad for the VB.Net devs who ask for help and all I have for them is C#. It's ok at work where they'll at least look at C#. A lot of the folks on SO won't even glance at a C# answer.

Comment: @Kibbee: C# is real code right? Too bad another VB.NET bashing session!

Comment: I actually love working in VB.Net.  I'd rather see a bunch of endifs and nexts than a bunch of curly braces.  Not to mention the background compiler rocks my world.

Answer (score 11):

Then next we'll have warnings for C and C++, fizz and buzz .. boom and bang .. where is it going to stop .. lisp and fainbruck?

I think this kind of automatic rejection / warning is just a bad idea, globally. It's way more expensive than it's worth.

Answer (score 11):

Considering they are using the same framework, and answers usually aren't that complex, it should be well within the abilities of any programmer to translate an answer from one .NET framework answer to another.

Even for VB.NET developers.